# Selector fails to find ins on page

Tags: ruby, xpath, capybara

I have a funky element on an html page that I am having trouble selecting with an XPath query.  I am using Capybara, however I hope this is an XPath problem.  Possibly the `-` character needs escape or bad query?

**HTML Element**

```
<ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; opacity: 0; background: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></ins>
```

**XPath**

`"//*[contains(@class, 'iCheck-helper')]"`

**Ruby/Capybara**

`elements = all(:xpath, myXPathQuery)` ([documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Finders#all-instance_method))

`elements.Count` is a [Capybara::Result](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Result).  `elements.count` returns 0 and I expect 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a specific reason you need to do this as XPath?  Capybara supports CSS selectors which are much easier to write for class names.

```
elements=all(:css, '.iCheck-helper')
```

Also when using all it returns immediately by default since it assumes no elements is a valid result.  If your page is dynamically changing and you know you are want at least one element you should do

```
elements=all(:css, '.iCheck-helper', minimum: 1)
```

which will wait up to Capybara.default_wait_time seconds for at least one matching element to appear. You could also pass count: 1 (instead of minimum) if you know for sure you only want one element and any more than that should be an error, although in that case #find probably makes more sense

I have just noticed your CSS which is scrolled off to the right which has opacity: 0 -  In any of the real browser drivers (selenium, capybara-webkit, poltergeist, etc - basically anything but racktest) that will make the element invisible so it will not be found by default.  To find that element you can do

```
elements=all(:css, '.iCheck-helper', minimum: 1, visible: :all)
```

Please note that since Capybara is meant to emulate a real user, finding invisible elements is usually not a good thing since a real user couldn't see it or interact with it.  Its generally a better idea to perform whatever action would make that element visible and then check for its existence/interact with it.

Comment: The architecture of this particular code base makes it awkward to switch to css.

Comment: I ended up selecting something else similar to your suggestion.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding your comment about the architecture of the code base but there's no need to swap all the tests to css, you can specify to override the default type of selector on a call by call basis with the first parameter as :css or :xpath  (or any of the other capybara provided (or custom) selector types).  If you skip the first parameter it defaults to Capybara.default_selector

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
myXPathQuery = '//ins[@class="iCheck-helper"]'
elements = all(:xpath, myXPathQuery)
```

Comment: I get an error saying invalid xpath with this format lookup for some strange reason.